# I am accessing remote machine in linux using Bash scripting

Tags: bash, ssh

I am accessing a remote machine using the ssh command and a pem file. My code is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -i rijo.pem ubuntu@90.45.74.51 <<EOF
sudo -s
var=`cat /opt/revsw-config/varnish/sites/rijotests4934567_revsw_net.json | egrep 'SERVER_NAME' | cut -b 19-44`
EOF
```

When I use this script, I am not able to store the value into the variable but if I run the command in the terminal it works. When I run the script, I get a `No such file or directory found` error.
Can u please help me in this.

Comment: If you are running `./yourscript.sh`, try it running by:`. ./yourscript.sh`

Comment: no its not working

Comment: Wait... how are you using this $var later? What are you trying to do? The lifetime of this variable is very short lived.

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
cat /opt/revsw-config/varnish/sites/rijotests4934567_revsw_net.json | egrep 'SERVER_NAME' | cut -b 19-44
```

is executed *locally* on your machine, before it is sent over to ssh. This is probably not what you wanted. The "here document" does variable and process substitution so you must escape the backticks to get the desired result.

Comment: ya this command is getting executed but i want to store that value into a variable

Comment: The local host will execute the command. The remote host will get something like
˙var=direct result of the command without quotes, possibly newlines...'
Unless it is one word, it won't even be a valid syntax and whatever gets into the new line, will get executed as a command (thus "file not found"). It's even dangerous in case a line starts with something that could be a valid command. Put quotes around it and if that doesn't help, consider transferring a file instead.

Comment: Or quote the marker for the here-doc: `<<"EOF"`.